Injecting a custom service into a hierarchy of components
I have a singleton service that I am passing as a parameter into a Index.razor. Index.razor is re-rendered when I clear the counter.  When I pass the same service to Component1 and click the Increase Count button the page is not re-rendered.  If I reload the page I can see the Counter increase.
Thank you for your assistance.

PS. I am not able to format the MyService class properly.  I tried several times.  My apologies.  I am new to Stack Overflow.
Service
namespace Injection.Pages

{
public class MyService
{
public int Counter { get; set; }
public void increaseCount()
{
Counter = Counter + 1;
    }

    public void clearCounter()
    {
        Counter = 0;
    }

}

}
Index
@page "/"
@inject MyService myService
<h3>Injection</h3>

<button @onclick="clearCounter">Clear Count</button>
<br />
<br />

@myService.Counter

<Component1 myService="myService" />

@code
{
    private void clearCounter ()
    {
        myService.clearCounter();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Component
    <h3>Component1</h3>

<button @onclick="increaseCount">Increase Count</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MyService myService { get; set; }

    private void increaseCount()
    {
        myService.increaseCount();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}


Inject everywhere you need it and only there. _Imports is for @include's, it does not wrap any other components.

Thank you for your response Henk.  When I injected directly in ContactForm Component and ContactList Componet I get the original error.   Counter Increments but the ContactList Component does not update.

Injection is not notification. You have to implement some sort of notification mechanism to call StateHasChanged() in the listening component(s).
Search INotifyPropertyChanged C# is one way.

I have included StateHasChanged() in the AddContact().   The state is changing because it's updating the Counter on the Page but not the sub component ContactList.
Thank you

As mentioned , inject in _imports makes the service globally available under that folder but does not notify the state change. Passing through a parameter makes the page re-render. Here is a sample
https://github.com/claudiobernasconi/BlazorParametersAndState/tree/main/BlazorParametersAndState  What's more I am a little confused about pass it as a parameter ... which resolved the issue . Since you have resolved you should have noticed the correct steps and focus on how to understand the rendering logic. Could you please explain what do you mean by your trys and errors in comments?

Thank you for your response Fengzhi.  "Passing through a parameter makes the page re-render." Yes that is correct when I pass the Service as a parameter to ContactList (2nd in the Hierarchy).  However, when I pass the parameter from ContactList to the Contact component (3d in the Hierarchy) the page doesn't re-render.  This further 2nd level of parameter passing does not re-render the page.  Please note that I am using StateHasChanged() and it doesn't re-render.

@Picard78 - you need to show some actually code., or create a [MRE].  At the moment imagining the code you have is pure guesswork.  Statements such as "Please note that I am using StateHasChanged() and it doesn't re-render" don't mean anything without knowing where and how you are calling it.

Understood.  I will create a minimal reproducible example.

I produced a minimal code example.  Please let me know if this is sufficient.  I apologize for the formatting of the MyServices class.  I tried several times to correct the formatting but with no luck.  Thank you.

In summary, though you have set the state, the change is not notified between components. Here is a sample.
Service
public class MyService
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public Action OnChange { get; set; }

    public void increaseCount()
    {
        Counter += 1;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    public void clearCounter()
    {
        Counter = 0;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => OnChange?.Invoke());
    }

}

Home
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp71.Components.Pages
@inject MyService myService

<h3>Injection</h3>

<button @onclick="clearCounter">Clear Count</button>
<br />
<br />

@myService.Counter

<Component1 myService="myService" />

@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        myService.OnChange += async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private void clearCounter()
    {
        myService.clearCounter();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myService.OnChange -= async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}

Component
<h3>Component1</h3>

<button @onclick="increaseCount">Increase Count</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MyService myService { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        myService.OnChange += async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private void increaseCount()
    {
        myService.increaseCount();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myService.OnChange += async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}

There are some other approaches to communicate between components
https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/  . You can refer to this for more information.

Thank you for the solution Fengzhi.  It works!
I will step through the code this weekend and digest it.  I am new to Blazor.  Started learning C# 10 days ago.
